# Remove notations not used

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I use custom notations in excel for the data labels of my graphs. I've already used a lot of the notations, but now I want to delete these, how can I do this?

For example in the picture below, I want to delete the ones with the pound symbol in it, but I can't find how.

[image]

Comment: none of the notations use the pound symbol? Do you mean the hashtag symbol?

Comment: @BilfredKerman yeah I mean the hashtag symbol (actually pound sign is just a synonym of hashtag)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the number format and then click delete;

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

Comment: I'm not at work right now, but I'll try it on monday

Comment: I can't see any delete button.. Do you have other suggestions?